# Inject <thead> default with table in tinymce

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, umbraco7, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor

I'm using Umbraco as the CMS, 7.6 - Umbraco.TinyMCEv3

[image]

So using insert Table will create HTML something like following

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
```

How can I configure to add default `<thead>` when table is created

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>…</tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to checkout the config file for TinyMCE in Umbraco. Go to `/config/tinyMceConfig.config` and search for `table` to see if you can find anything.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I have checked it first, but not able to find any thing that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is all that possible; it seems as though that functionality isn't included as a setting within the editor.

The obvious thing to do if the setting isn't included is to create it yourself - the way to to do this would be to either extend the existing editor or copy and paste the editor to a new one locally.

The files for the editor are under \Umbraco\lib\tinymce

Unfortunately, it appears the angular js file associated with this editor is only available as a non-human readable minified version - likely owing to the fact that tinymce is under license. So any modification of this would be quite tricky, to say the least.

Perhaps see if there is another way around this? You can always set css to select the first child row of the table if it is for styling purposes. Otherwise the only other option would be to create your table in the editor, then choose the code edit option to manually insert the correct table structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have v5 with vue.js

After created table:

1-Click right on row of head you want > row > row properties

[click right on row of head>row>row properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMjpW.jpg)

2-In general choose "Header" at Row type

[in general select of "Header" at Row type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXPk2.jpg)